# Java web app deployed in bluemix

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, ibm-cloud

i deployed a java web app in bluemix which is using db2 jdbc, i am getting sqlnontransient exception stating that my host is unknown ,which is ibm internal ,but it is working fine in my local enviornment

com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlNonTransientConnectionException: [jcc][t4][10380][11951][4.13.127] Required property "" is unknown host. ERRORCODE=-4222, SQLSTATE=08001

Comment: Please share the code you are using, and what line is trowing this error ;)

Comment: public  static boolean checkConnection(String user, String password)
 {        
       String className="COM.ibm.db2os390.sqlj.jdbc.DB2SQLJDriver";       
  try {
   Class.forName(className);
   System.out.println("Driver Loaded & registered (Driver Manager)"); 
  } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   }
  String url="jdbc:db2://IBMNLYC02.NL.IBM.COM:50000/pbs3db";
  Connection conn=null;
  try {
    conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);
   System.out.println("connection established.....>");
   return true;   
  }

Comment: i used above code, and getconnection method throwing error

Answer (score 0):

IBM Bluemix is on the public internet. If your database is on the IBM Internal Network you will not be able to reach it due to firewall restrictions. If your local environment is also in the internal IBM network this is why it works there but not in Bluemix. You will need to use the API Gateway to reach your data which will require you to write a REST API in front of your datasource and register it with the gateway.

If the data is not confidential, a better approach might be to request a DB2 Cloud instance in Bluemix and place your data there. If your data cannot be placed in the public Bluemix, IBM has a Bluemix Dedicated instance that is on the internal network. You should probably deploy your application there instead.

~jr